# Area 51 login failure

Tags: bug, area-51, login, openid, error-message

I tried to login to Area 51 through my Stack Exchange OpenID, and it asked me if I can provide my account information to this site.

It says: "send your Stack Exchange account information to this site?".

[image: Screenshot]

I know that this happens when one is not registered, and as a network user, it must instead say that one is creating a new account on this site, because one would have used the same credential to login to his/her Stack Exchange profile. But I had already created an Area 51 account using Google OpenID (I also use my Google OpenID as a login), so naturally I must be able to login to it using my Stack Exchange OpenID, but it shows the above mentionded message of providing info to this site.

I was afraid that a totally new Stack Exchange profile would be created, so I tried to login through my Google OpenID, but it said that an error occurred.

[image: Screenshot]

(I appologise for the volume bar; it can't be avoided in this smartphone while taking screenshots.)

Please fix this as soon as possible.

Comment: "I appologise for the volume bar, it cant be avoided in this smartphone while taking screenshots." - ur serious?

Comment: @nicael this is a 'Samsung Galaxy Star Pro Duos    GT S7262'. To take a screen shot one has to simultaniously press hold the power-button+home-button+volume-down-button. The last one is the main proble. I just dont know why the heck this happens

Comment: When was this? I don't see any exceptions in our logs, but I may be just missing the relevant error. A timeframe would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the code in front of me, but I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is just an OpenID login workflow - you authenticate with Stack Exchange Open ID and then it provides your identity to Area 51. So that part seems normal. Clicking the "login" button should get you into the right account assuming you're logging in with the same credentials as you use on the Q&A sites.

The error while logging in with Google is more concerning. Gonna have to look more into that next week.

Comment: Did you look at this? I also have the exact same Google error.

Comment: @Fiksdal No idea, it's been a year. What you're seeing is probably new? I don't see anything relevant and recent in the error logs, though. Mind posting a new bug report with the details? Thanks!

Comment: It's back now. I've made a [new question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284924/why-cant-i-log-in-to-area-51), as requested.